# Qt Thread worker QMutex слоты

Tags: многопоточность, qt5

Есть worker содержащий массив данных
Он реализует run-метод который выполняется в потоке и обрабатывает массив(как - не важно)
Общение с worker-ом происходит через сигналы-слоты.
Есть слот который изменяет массив(как - не важно) во время работы потока.
Так вот, вопрос: надо ли в этом слоте и в run-не оборачивать работу с массивом мьютексом?
Или в процессе вызова слота не требуется синхронизация?
В каком контексте будет работать слот после moveToThread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я ничего не путаю, то мьютекс не блокирует непосредственно переменную - он блокирует обращение к памяти. Т.е. если поставить мьютекс внутри слота, то он заблокирует лишь повторный вызов слота. А два раза одновременно слот вызван быть не может (кажется). Следовательно, на слот и run мьютексы не нужны.

После moveToThread слот будет работать в контексте той среды, куда был помещен объект, если вызов слота будет осуществляться по сигналу. Если же вызывать слот, как обычную функцию - то в контексте вызвавшего объекта.

UPD: если вы меняете массив в run-е и в слоте одной и той же функцией - то имеет смысл повесить мьютекс на эту функцию.

Comment: Что значит **одной и той же** функцией?  
В run-не чтение того , что в массиве, а слоте замена содержимого массива  
Следовательно **однозначно** мьютекс?

Comment: Имеется ввиду, что для обработки массива и в run-е, и в слоте вызывается одна и та же функция. В этом случае, при повторной попытке вызова этой функции до завершения выполнения первого вызова мьютекс приостановит выполнение того вычислительного потока, который пытался получить доступ к функции вторым.

Если у вас реализовано не так, то мьютекс не нужен

Comment: Если вызов слота будет осуществляться по сигналу, соединенному со слотом через `DirectConnection`, то слот будет выполнен в том потоке, из которого испущен сигнал. Так что второе утверждение не до конца верно.